# How to copy image upload function from UserController to LinkController

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have UserController which has this function to upload users avatar:

```
    public function update_avatar(Request $request){

        if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->fit(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ) );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save();
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->with(['success' => 'Profile picture updated!']);

    }
```

Now, each user can make and edit his links (Kind of like Linktree) and I want to add an option where they can upload a custom icon for their links. This is the code which I came up with and it successfully uploads my file to desired path but it fails to write it to Links Table. Here is the code:

```
    public function custom_icon(Request $request){

        if($request->hasFile('icon')){
            $uploaded_icon = $request->file('icon');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $uploaded_icon->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($uploaded_icon)->fit(300, 300)->save( public_path('/img/icons/' . $filename ) );

            $link = Auth::user()->link()
            $link->icon = $filename;
            $link->save();
        }

        return redirect()->back()
            ->with(['success' => 'Custom icon uploaded!']);

    }
```

Now, I am new to coding and I have no idea how to add similar code like this to LinkController

```
   $user = Auth::user();
```

I tried a few things but nothing works. This is one example:

```
   $link = Auth::user()->link()
```

Note that the link edit page is opened by links id so maybe I am failing to add a good route?
Here is web.php

```
    Route::get('/links', [LinkController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('/links/new', [LinkController::class, 'create'])->middleware('verified');
    Route::post('/links/new', [LinkController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::post('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'destroy']);
    Route::post('/links/{link}', [LinkController::class, 'custom_icon']);
```

User model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'tittle',
        'bio',
        'bio_show',
        'bio_on',
        'bio_off',
        'background_color',
        'button_border_radius',
        'button_text_color',
        'button_color',
        'text_color',
        'editable_link',
        'vcard_prefix',
        'vcard_first_name',
        'vcard_middle_name',
        'vcard_last_name',
        'vcard_suffix',
        'vcard_email',
        'vcard_second_email',
        'vcard_personal_number',
        'vcard_work_number',
        'vcard_company',
        'vcard_job',
        'vcard_address',
        'vcard_website',
        'vcard_second_website',
        'vcard_show',
        'vcard_on',
        'vcard_off'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function links()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Link::class);
    }

    public function visits()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Visit::class, Link::class);
    }
    
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your User model?

Comment: I posted it as an answer since it was to long to post here.

Answer (score 1):

The `Auth::user()` returns you the User model. With the code `Auth::user()->link()` you call the link() method in your `User` model. But there is no such method in your `User` model.

If you want to get the last `Link`, you can add a method like this in your `User` model:

```
public function link() {
   return $this->hasOne(Link::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

Comment: It brings me to the error I run into few times before: Attempt to assign property "icon" on null

Comment: @caktasnino `$link = Auth::user()->link()` after line `dd($link);` If you do, you can see what it returns. If it is `null`, you can create and save a new `Link` model for that user within the framework of **your desired logic**.

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne {#1290 ▼
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1288 ▶}
  #parent: App\Models\User {#1041 ▶}
  #related: App\Models\Link {#363 ▶}
  #foreignKey: "links.user_id"
  #localKey: "id"
  #isOneOfMany: true
  #relationName: "latestOfMany"
  #oneOfManySubQuery: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1289 ▶}
  #withDefault: null
}` but now I have error `Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\\LinkController.php on line 102 and exactly 1 expected`